# Trouble Placing a Div Over a Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried the solutions I've seen on here: changing `z-index`, `absolute` positioning, etc. When I tried using the absolute position it shrinks the `navbar` to 600px. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.jumbotron {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 0;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #3b4e6b;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 25px;
 }

.topnav .icon {
   /* Hide icon to expand menu */
  display: none;
}

/* When screen is less than 600px wide, hide all links except the first one, and display the icon to expand the menu */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
   .topnav a.icon {
   float: right;
   display: block;
   }
}

/* When screen is less than 600px wide, display all links vertically when icon is clicked */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
 }
 .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. _"Absolute position of 'topnav' won't work because of the media query that uses absolute position."_ - c'mon, that doesn't even make sense ... Explain first of all exactly what you are trying to _achieve_ here - so far we only have the question title in that regard, and it isn't exactly specific either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`z-index` only works when `position` property is assigned,

so use `z-index: -1` and `position:relative` in `.jumbotron` ( with `top: negative value at your choice` )

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.jumbotron {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('//lorempixel.com/600/600');
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  top: -64px /* value of topnav height */
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  /* changed for demo purposes*/
  overflow: hidden
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 25px;
}

.topnav .icon {
  /* Hide icon to expand menu */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
<div class="jumbotron"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just added what you suggested and it works. I added some Javascript code to calculate the correct top offset with out hardcoding it.